# Curl command no return

Tags: api, curl

Im working with an api, in the documentaion found here:
http://api.simplicate.nl/ 
There is an example curl:

```
`curl -H “Authentication-Key: {API Key}” -H “Authentication-Secret:{API secret}” https://{subdomain}.simplicate.nl/api/v2/crm/organization.json`
```

I ran that code like this in terminal:

```
curl -H “Authentication-Key:XX” -H “Authentication-Secret:XX” https://mydomain.simplicate.nl/api/v2/crm/organization.json
```

It runs but returns nothing.

Comment: Add `-v` argument to the curl command and check for any errors.

Comment: so instead of -H i use -v? @ArminSam

Comment: No, just add -v after curl...

Comment: @ArminSam so i just ran it, it returns a bunch of stuff. for example the first 3 lines * IDN support not present, can't parse Unicode domains
* Could not resolve host: “Authentication-Key; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: “Authentication-Key; nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: Maybe you can add the output here (after removing your key and secret information).

Comment: donee @ArminSam

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` you're receiving HTTP 401 error, which means your credentials are wrong. It seems you did not provide the `Authentication-Key` in your request header?

Comment: Pretty sure my credentials were right, removed after removing http infront of the url it seemed to work. i got an output now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Header inside `“...”` that is wrong. You have to use double quote `"..."` (not sure what it is called, standard double quote?).

So it should be:

```
curl -H "Authentication-Key:XX" -H "Authentication-Secret:XX" https://mydomain.simplicate.nl/api/v2/crm/organization.json
```

As a note, currently your curl is sending the headers as following with extra characters.

```
“Authentication-Key:XX”
“Authentication-Secret:XX”
```

But it should be:

```
Authentication-Key:XX
Authentication-Secret:XX
```