# curl-Command returning html instead of node.js

Tags: node.js, json, facebook, curl, heroku

I'm trying to create and host a webhook via heroku, using this Facebook-messenger-tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup.
Therefore, I'm currently testing cURL-requests to my local host. This request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:3000/" -d "{""object"": ""page"", ""entry"": [{""messaging"": [{""message"": ""TEST_MESSAGE""}]}]}"
```

should return EVENT RECEIVED in the cmd, and TEST_MESSAGE in a second cmd-window, where I'm executing my application. 
For executing the application, I used $ node index.js, and I'm receiving "webhook listening" which means to me there is no mistake in the way I execute it.

This is how my file index.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates express http server

// Sets server port and logs message on success
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('webhook is listening'));
// Creates the endpoint for our webhook 
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  

  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

      // Gets the message. entry.messaging is an array, but 
      // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
      let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
      console.log(webhook_event);
    });

    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});
// Adds support for GET requests to our webhook
app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
  let VERIFY_TOKEN = "somepassword"

  // Parse the query params
  let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
  let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];

  // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
  if (mode && token) {

    // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
    if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {

      // Responds with the challenge token from the request
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
      res.status(200).send(challenge);

    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);      
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the respond I'm getting (some html-code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**I do not receive an error, just the "wrong" return.**

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this and receive "EVENT RECEIVED" and "TEST_MESSAGE"?

Note: I have seen the follwoing articles, [Curl command no return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802439/curl-command-no-return), [Prometheus API returning HTML instead of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005111/prometheus-api-returning-html-instead-of-json) and I did change something of the code from the tutorial relating to [Facebook messenger bot error Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754510/facebook-messenger-bot-error-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0), but I am still not able to fix this.

I also read [How do I POST JSON data with Curl from a terminal/commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl-from-a-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-res), but it didn't solve my problem, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget include /webhook in the url that you use in curl command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:3000/webhook"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Worked for me. What a stupid mistake!